# How do you exclude only some numbers from string input on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm wanting to figure out how do you exclude on some numbers from a string input. For example, If I were to input this "https://www.shoepalace.com/products/jordan-dr6287-486-air-jordan-5-low-doernbecher-mens-lifestyle-shoes-blue-multi?variant=41679925772494", I'd want "?variant=41679925772494" remove and keep the rest the same. I can't use a constant of "?variant=41679925772494" because I'm wanting it work across all string inputs, not the same one. what I have is below, but it removes all numbers within the link, rather than whats after "?variant=". Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about this?

````
let updatedLink = link.replace("?variant=", "")
let variantLink = updatedLink.replace(/[0-9]/g, "")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse URL's, using regex is not really the best option.

Browsers have the `URL` class that does exactly what your after.

eg.

```js
var n = new URL('https://www.shoepalace.com/products/jordan-dr6287-486-air-jordan-5-low-doernbecher-mens-lifestyle-shoes-blue-multi?variant=41679925772494');

n.searchParams.delete('variant');

console.log(n.toString());
```